# Why I can't pass a simple array with Jquery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I have some simple code and i'm getting

> HTTP Status 400 â€“ Bad Request
>   Type Status Report
>
> Message Required String[] parameter 'testCaseNames' is not present

When it clearly is in the formData part using chrome developer tools.

```
flowName: gsaasggsa
params[]: QUERY=select 1 from cuvar
params[]: PASSWORD=xasf
params[]: USERNAME={{ 0.OUTPUT }}
params[]: PASSWORD=xxx
params[]: USERNAME={{ 0.OUTPUT }}
testCaseNames[]: sql_test
testCaseNames[]: test_loginFail
testCaseNames[]: test_loginSuccess
```

What am I missing here? Why I cant pass it??

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "/flow/import",
    data: {
        linkageObject: linkageObject,
        flowName: flowName,
        params: params,
        testCaseNames: testCaseNames
    },
    success: function() {
        new PNotify({
            title: 'Flow Creation',
            text: 'Flow was imported successfully. It is available for use',
            type: 'success'
        });
        location.href = "/execute-flow";
    }
});
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/flow/import" , method = RequestMethod.POST
public @ResponseBody String importFlow(
    HttpSession session,
    @RequestParam("flowName") String flowName,
    @RequestParam("testCaseNames") String[] testCaseNames,
    @RequestParam(value = "params", required = false) String[] params,
    @RequestParam(value = "linkageObject", required = false) String linkageObject) { 

}
```

EDIT: I didn't put the linkageObject.

```
linkageObject=%22%7B%5C%22operators%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22operator0%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22top%5C%22%3A160%2C%5C%22left%5C%22%3A640%2C%5C%22properties%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22title%5C%22%3A%5C%22sql_test+(SQL)%5C%22%2C%5C%22inputs%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22input_0%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22QUERY%5C%22%7D%7D%2C%5C%22outputs%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22output_0%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22OUTPUT%5C%22%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%5C%22operator1%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22top%5C%22%3A260%2C%5C%22left%5C%22%3A920%2C%5C%22properties%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22title%5C%22%3A%5C%22test_loginFail+(CSR)%5C%22%2C%5C%22inputs%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22input_0%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22USERNAME%5C%22%7D%2C%5C%22input_1%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22PASSWORD%5C%22%7D%7D%2C%5C%22outputs%5C%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%2C%5C%22operator2%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22top%5C%22%3A100%2C%5C%22left%5C%22%3A920%2C%5C%22properties%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22title%5C%22%3A%5C%22test_loginSuccess+(CSR)%5C%22%2C%5C%22inputs%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22input_0%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22USERNAME%5C%22%7D%2C%5C%22input_1%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22label%5C%22%3A%5C%22PASSWORD%5C%22%7D%7D%2C%5C%22outputs%5C%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%7D%7D%2C%5C%22links%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%221%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22fromOperator%5C%22%3A%5C%22operator0%5C%22%2C%5C%22fromConnector%5C%22%3A%5C%22output_0%5C%22%2C%5C%22fromSubConnector%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22toOperator%5C%22%3A%5C%22operator2%5C%22%2C%5C%22toConnector%5C%22%3A%5C%22input_0%5C%22%2C%5C%22toSubConnector%5C%22%3A0%7D%2C%5C%222%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22fromOperator%5C%22%3A%5C%22operator0%5C%22%2C%5C%22fromConnector%5C%22%3A%5C%22output_0%5C%22%2C%5C%22fromSubConnector%5C%22%3A0%2C%5C%22toOperator%5C%22%3A%5C%22operator1%5C%22%2C%5C%22toConnector%5C%22%3A%5C%22input_0%5C%22%2C%5C%22toSubConnector%5C%22%3A0%7D%7D%2C%5C%22operatorTypes%5C%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%22&flowName=gsaasggsa&params%5B%5D=QUERY%3Dselect+1+from+cuvar&params%5B%5D=PASSWORD%3Dxasf&params%5B%5D=USERNAME%3D%7B%7B+0.OUTPUT+%7D%7D&params%5B%5D=PASSWORD%3Dxxx&params%5B%5D=USERNAME%3D%7B%7B+0.OUTPUT+%7D%7D&testCaseNames%5B%5D=sql_test&testCaseNames%5B%5D=test_loginFail&testCaseNames%5B%5D=test_loginSuccess
```

Full code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(event) {
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
    var testCaseNames = [],
        params = [];
    var linkageObject = null;
    $.each(jsonObject, function(index, testCase) {
        console.log(testCase);
        if (testCase.hasOwnProperty("linkageObject")) {
            linkageObject = JSON.stringify(testCase.linkageObject);
        } else {
            var testCaseName = testCase.name.split("/")[1].split('.')[0];
            testCaseNames.push(testCaseName);
            $.each(testCase.inputs, function(k, v) {
                params.push(k + "=" + v);
            });
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "/flow/import",
        //url: '/flow/import?flowName=' + flowName + "&testCaseNames=" + testCaseNames + "&params=" + params,
        data: {
            linkageObject: linkageObject,
            flowName: flowName,
            params: params,
            testCaseNames: testCaseNames
        },
        success: function() {
            new PNotify({
                title: 'Flow Creation',
                text: 'Flow was imported successfully. It is available for use',
                type: 'success'
            });
            location.href = "/execute-flow";
        }
    });
};
reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

Comment: In Chrome developer tools, under the Network tab, can you get the `Form Data / Request Payload` "raw" data (click `View Source`) and put that info in your question? Also, in the `Request Headers` what does the `content-type` say?

Comment: Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 . I will post the source on my edit.

Comment: **before someone says it's about the linkageObject, it's not because if I remove that I get the same error.**

Comment: You are submitting testCaseNames[].. so in your java code try `@RequestParam("testCaseNames[]")`

Comment: @Joschi i will try. wait

Comment: @Joschi lol it worked...